# Is there a way to increase tinydb JSON limit?

Tags: python, tinydb

I have a tinydb json file but I noticed that at a certain point it refuses to write more items to the json file and throws an error while parsing because it cut off in the middle of writing an item

This is the traceback. It shows the json parser failing to parse because the writer cut off writing in the middle of an item

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "main.py", line 79, in run
    message.process()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\dbtest\Login_Message.py", line 45, in process
    DataBase.loadAccount(self)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\dbtest\DataBase.py", line 9, in loadAccount
    user_data = db.search(query.token == str(user.token))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tinydb\table.py", line 234, in search
    docs = [doc for doc in self if cond(doc)]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tinydb\table.py", line 234, in <listcomp>
    docs = [doc for doc in self if cond(doc)]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tinydb\table.py", line 588, in __iter__
    for doc_id, doc in self._read_table().items():
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tinydb\table.py", line 638, in _read_table
    tables = self._storage.read()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tinydb\storages.py", line 125, in read
    return json.load(self._handle)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 234357 (char 234356)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happened was because multiple threads were writing to the db file at the same time so I ended up manually writing to multiple files: one for every entry